# Adding rows to existing xml file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to add rows to existing xml file. Currently i use below;

```
dtMasterPivot.WriteXml(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + pathname);
```

dtMasterPivot is a datatable that has 1000+ rows and its data updates every 15 seconds. That's why i don't want to rewrite the whole xml file from scratch every 15 seconds.

What i want is, appending the 'result' to existing xml ;

```
var result = (from dr1 in dtTADetailsTempOld.AsEnumerable()
                      from dr2 in dtTADetailsTemp.AsEnumerable()
                      where dr1.Field<int>("INST_ID") == dr2.Field<int>("INST_ID")
                      select new
                      {
                          SAMPLE_TIME = dr1.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME"),
                          CPU = Math.Round((dr2.Field<double>(1) - dr1.Field<double>(1)) / (timeTopActivity * 100), 2),
                          INST_ID = dr1.Field<int>("INST_ID"),
                      }).ToDataTable();
```

The example xml content is like beloW;

```
<DocumentElement>
  <dtMasterPivot>
    <SAMPLE_TIME>2017-08-02T09:53:14+03:00</SAMPLE_TIME>
    <CPU>0</CPU>
    <INST_ID>1</INST_ID>
  </dtMasterPivot>
</DocumentElement>
```

Which path should i follow ?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `XDocument` class for editing XML files. You can simply load and add rows like this:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(FilePath);
var root = xdoc.Descendants("DocumentElement").FirstOrDefault()
if (root != null){
    root.Add(new XElement("tag", "value"));
    xdoc.Save(FilePath);
}
```

Comment: hi, could you please make it using above code as an answer ?

Comment: @doctorcesar I think only you can do that. You simply need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image)